# Hide field when creating a node

Tags: 7, nodes

How can I hide a field when creating a node, but displaying it when editing a node?

Comment: You could take over the node add/edit form with Panel pages. With this, you can pick and choose what you want on the form.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think that you can use a custom module (in this example, the name of the module is `test_remove_field`) and include the following code:

```
function test_remove_field_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

    if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'add') {
    $form['field_test']['#access'] = 0;
    }

}
```

Note: remember that `field_test` must be your respective field name.

Comment: Hello a.v., regarding your question, yes, is possible, you can add the same IF declaration in page.tpl.php (inside head zone) and add inside the declaration the respective (ID or CLASS) CSS rule to remove your field: #field_name_test { display:none;}

Comment: here is the code of my test:

<?php
 if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'add') {
    ?>
 <style type="text/css">
 #field_name_test
    {
    display:none;
    }
 </style>
 <?php
    }
 ?>

Answer (score 4):

The **[Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions)** module allows you to set field level permissions:

- Create field (edit on content creation)
- Edit field regardless of content author
- Edit own field on content created by the user
- View field regardless of content author
- View own field on content created by the user

You can use these options to enable role based permission for a field.

> When permissions are enabled, access to this field is denied by
>   default and explicit permissions should be granted to the proper user
>   roles from the permissions administration page. On the other hand,
>   when these options are disabled, field permissions are inherited from
>   the content view and/or edit permissions. In example, users allowed to
>   view a particular node will also be able to view this field, and so
>   on.

*Field permissions*

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and set the [`#access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#access) property to `FALSE` just like the answer by @moon.watcher. In Drupal 7, you can call [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) from your template.

Answer (score 2):

This is a use case for the Rules Form Support Module - https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_forms.

**Features include:**

> - Activate events for form creation, validation, and submission on a form-by-form basis.
> - Target individual form elements or the entire form in conditions and actions.
>     Manipulate the attributes of a form element like title, description, weight, and more.
> - Validate the values of form elements during form validation.
> - Set form errors when rule-based validation fails.
> - Redirect users to a different page upon viewing or submitting a form.
> - Examine the attributes of elements in active forms with the element inspection tool.