# How to hide certain fields on the User Edit form?

Tags: users, forms

So I have three types of users - admin, LA admin and users. 
I am trying to set it up so that admins and LA admins cannot edit the username, password and timezone for users. I am talking about the default user edit form for admins and the form ID is "user-profile-form".

I have created a custom module but this doesn't seem to be working. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Even the var_dump does not seem to be outputting. I have cleared the cache and verified that the module is enabled.

```
function profile_change_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id === 'user-profile-form') {
    // Use var_dump  to dump the $form array to see the fields. 
        var_dump ($form);

        hide($form['account']['pass']);
        hide($form['account']['current_pass_required_values']);
        hide($form['account']['current_pass']);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide field in "node/add" page](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11237/hide-field-in-node-add-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace form id `user-profile-form` with `user_profile_form`

Your code should look like the following:

```
function profile_change_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // changed form id
    if ($form_id === 'user_profile_form') {
        // Use var_dump  to dump the $form array to see the fields. 
        var_dump ($form);

        hide($form['account']['pass']);
        hide($form['account']['current_pass_required_values']);
        hide($form['account']['current_pass']);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use also `$form['account']['pass']['#access'] = FALSE;`

Comment: @milkovsky True. Also, `unset($form['account']['pass']);`

Comment: $form['account']['pass']['#access'] = FALSE;  using this line resetting the user role from admin to normal.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work if you want to disable the field instead of hiding them.

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    if ($user->uid != 1) {
      $form['field_joining_date']["#disabled"] = TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```

Replace the 'field_joining_date' by your custom field name.